# Illustrating a decision tree with splits using R

Tags: r, igraph, decision-tree

I found a graphic online that I am trying to replicate in R. I have managed to create the first graphic of the image below and now I am trying to construct the decision tree. It is only for illustrative purposes so it will not form part of some model.

[image]

Code to generate the first plot:

```
x1 <- sample(c(1:100), 100, replace = TRUE)
x2 <- sample(c(1:100), 100, replace = TRUE)

d <- data.frame(x1, x2)

d %>% 
  mutate(
    colours = case_when(
      x1 < 50 & x2 >= 60 ~ "green",
      x1 >= 50 & x2 >= 60 ~ "red",
      x1 < 70 & x2 < 60 ~ "red",
      x1 >= 70 & x2 < 20 ~ "red",
      x1 > 70 & x2 > 20 ~ "green"
    )
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x1, y = x2)) +
  geom_point(aes( color = colours)) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(1, 100), y = c(60, 60)), aes(x = x , y = y), linetype = "dashed") +
  annotate("text", label = "Split 1", x = 105, y = 60) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(50, 50), y = c(60, 100)), aes(x = x, y = y), linetype = "dashed") +
  annotate("text", label = "Split 2", x = 50, y = 101) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(70, 70), y = c(1, 60)), aes(x = x, y = y), linetype = "dashed") +
  annotate("text", label = "Split 3", x = 70, y = 61) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(70, 100), y = c(20, 20)), aes(x = x, y = y), linetype = "dashed") +
  annotate("text", label = "Split 4", x = 105, y = 20)
```

Which gives:

[image]

How can I now create the decision tree part? I am looking into the `igraph` package but do not know where to begin with it when generating a decision tree model.

Comment: see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggparty/vignettes/ggparty-graphic-partying.html for a vignette of the `ggparty` package that plots ggplot graphics from trees fitted with the `partykit` package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your question is more about how to create trees with `ggplot2`. But if you just want to visualize decision tree models `rpart` and `rpart.plot` are a good solution.

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
# Create model
tree <- rpart(mpg~., data=mtcars, cp=.05)
# Visualize Tree
rpart.plot(tree, box.palette=c("green","red","blue"), shadow.col="gray", nn=TRUE)
```

[image]

There are also lots of ways to customize this plot. By setting the parameters of `rpart.plot` you can make it look nearly exactly like your example.